# Display paragraph value inside textarea

Tags: javascript

Hello i have the following code : http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Zk/

```
var makeAreaEditable = function(event){
    var btn = event.target,
        li  = btn.parentNode,
        p   = li.getElementsByClassName('paratext')[0];

    p.style.display="none";
    btn.innerText="Ok";
    btn.onclick = saveEdit;
    var textareaEdit = document.createElement('textarea');
    textareaEdit.className = 'testarea';
    li.appendChild(textareaEdit);
    textareaEdit.appendChild(p);
    textareaEdit.style.display="block";
};
```

The problem is that i want the paragraf  display: none when i press the button edit but i want it displaied in the textarea.. so please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
textareaEdit.appendChild(p);
```

into:

```
textareaEdit.value = p.innerHTML;
```

Comment: the thing is now when i press ok the button is gone... so i need the appendchild i guess. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/yw7Zk/4/

Comment: I figure it out... i just need to ADD your line of code and it work perfectly. thank you